# How to make some operation with a whole 3d array in R

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

Suppose I've got a 3d array `Arr`:

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    0    1
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    4    0    0

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
```

Now I want to perform `unique()` operation for `Arr[,,1]`, `Arr[,,2]`, `Arr[,,3]`. 
Is there a simple way to do this without loops? Something like:

```
Arr = unique(Arr[,,1:3])
```

But the line above doesn't work for me, I need `Arr` to become:

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    0    1
[2,]    0    0    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    4    0    0

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    1    0
```

Like if it was

```
Arr[,,1] = unique(Arr[,,1])
Arr[,,2] = unique(Arr[,,2])
Arr[,,3] = unique(Arr[,,3])
```

Comment: Try `array(apply(Arr, 3, unique), c(2, 4, 3))`

Comment: akrun, this works fine for me! Could you please explain what с(2, 4, 3) means? I'm very new with R. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is difficult to do this on array setting.  what if the number of unique rows were different.  I would do `lapply(seq(dim(Arr)[3]), function(i) unique(Arr[,,i]))`   The `c(2, 4, 3)` is manual dimensions after finding that there are 2 unique rows on each of the elements of the third dimension.

Comment: I would get the results in a `list` with `lapply`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to store the results in a `list` as `unique` rows can be different for the elements in the third dimension.

```
lapply(seq(dim(Arr)[3]), function(i) unique(Arr[,,i]))
```

Here, we loop over the sequence of third dimension, subset the 'Arr' (`Arr[,,i]`) and get the `unique`.